# The class 'Login\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces \Entity

Tags: zend-framework2, doctrine

i'm using zf2 and doctrine that i've configured module.config.php like this

```
return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__. '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__.'\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__.'_driver'
            )
        )
    )
),
```

and my LoginController

```
class LoginController extends AbstractRestfulController  {

    public function indexAction() {

        $em = $this->getServiceLocator()-> get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        $usr = new User();
        $usr->setUsername('yassine');
        $usr->setPassword('yassine');
        $usr->setEmail('yassine@gmail.com');
        $em->persist($usr);
        $em->flush(); } }
```

and my class user /Login/Entity/User

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(name="id")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="username")
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="password")
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="email")
 */
protected $email;

  // Returns ID of the user
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

// Sets ID of the user.
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

// Returns username.
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

// Sets username.
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

// Returns password.
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

// Sets Password.
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

// Sets email.
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

// Returns email.
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
```

}

The problem that it shows me this message Mapping Exception :

The class 'Login\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces \Entity

Comment: Do you have something like `namespace Login;` in that `module.config.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `__NAMESPACE__` is empty in your `module.config.php` and that’s why Doctrine sees the following:

```php
'drivers' => [
    '\Entity' => '_driver'
]
```

instead of:

```php
'drivers' => [
    'Login\Entity' => 'Login_driver'
]
```

To fix this issue, you have to declare the [namespace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) used in `module.config.php`. In other words, put the following:

```php
namespace Login;
```

at the top of the file, right after PHP opening tag.

Another solution would be to replace all `__NAMESPACE__` occurrences with `'Login'` string.